# Static files are not loaded. Deploying Django app to VPS with Ngnix and Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn

It's my first time I am trying to deploy django project to Digital Ocean droplet(instance) and set up with Gunicorn and Nginx. I'v got problem with static files because there are not loaded. It seems I messed things up because in tutorials `static` is usually located in (in my case) `glboy/` and localy in my project it was located in `glboy/app/`. So I now there is folder `/root/glboy/static` and everything is copied there by `python manage.py collectstatic` . I can't understand what is wrong. I tried various things and restarted after every change  `sudo service nginx restart` but nothing helped. What is likely to be wrong?

In `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/closer`:

```
 location /static/ {
    root /home/root/glboy/; 
    expires 30d;
}
```

In    `sudo nano  /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
  location /static/ {
        root /home/root/glboy/;
        expires 30d;
    }
```

In `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

EDIT:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Structure is like that. I am not sure what is before in unix. As far as I understand it's like home/root/

glboy/

app/, closer/, denv/, static/, manage.py, myapp.log

EDIT2: Main tutorial I'v been following if helps https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: can you post your glboy directory tree and your BASE_DIR from django settings? i have many at this point but i need to give more details to be precise.
Meanwhile try removing the static folder in glboy, run collectstatic again and tell me if the folder is created at the same place (in case you changed STATIC_ROOT and forgot)

Comment: @HassenPy static appeared at the same place with all files copied again. I'l update details in a second

Comment: lol, i don't remember writing my comment the way it is, i'm basically skipping  words, but ye, you got the idea xD

Comment: what happens? do you get 404s? did you check your log files?

Comment: @Udi nothing in log

Comment: what do you get when you browse /static/foo ? 404? 500? check your dev tools.

Comment: @Udi 404 not found

Comment: Django doesn't itself serves the static files when debug mode is off. You could use a middleware like whitenoise: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

Comment: what message the nginx access logs give when you access a static file?

Comment: @HassenPy I'll check in while. Up until then I noticed that nginx.conf is not set up like two other files (because I was following tutorials). Can it be the reason?

Comment: nope, nginx.conf is main configuration file, just keep your app's server settings separate from it, i think nginx's access logs will hold the answer for this, just make sure you try access a static file before checking the logs.

Comment: @HessenPy Ok, it's multiple '(2: No such file or directory)' on every static file required in log

Comment: basically, these are my last guesses, wich i think you've stumbled upon while searching for a solution to your error, but i ll write them anyway.  
to this point, i think its not a path thing cause the nginx static location conf is correct as `/home/root/glboy/static` exists, so now we're left with these questions, does nginx have read rights on your static folder? or maybe you're not serving the static files on the same port the django app is running on? (so the static path is for eg: `ip:8001/static` instead of `ip:8000/static`)

Comment: @HassenPy tried to bind on 8001 -  same thing with static. Is it right that I have to use paths like this /home/root/glboy/ in settings files? As I guess, /home/root/ is unix stuff and in command line I can access only to root ~/ but in in settings it's right to set full path? I mean can I change for example  in default ' root  /home/root/glboy/ ' to  'root   /glboy/ ' - may it work as well?

Comment: @HassenPy Maybe it will help. The path where it searches for it "/app/static/static/img/settingsbutton.png" failed (2: No such file or directory),

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131491/discussion-between-hassenpy-and-vinand).